# Stop substitutions in vim function from leaking out into history of all substitutions

Tags: vim

I have a pre-buffer write hook set up in vim that makes a few small adjustments before the contents of the buffer is saved out to a file.

```
if !exists("autocommands_loaded")
    let autocommands_loaded = 1
    autocmd BufWritePre *.php call TidyUpFormatting()
endif

func! TidyUpFormatting()
    let save_cursor = getpos('.')
    %s/\s\+$//ge
    %s/\($\n\s*\)\+\%$//ge
    %s/var_dump /var_dump/ge 
    %s/){/) {/ge
    %s/( /(/ge
    %s/if(/if (/ge
    %s/while(/while (/ge
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction
```

This is in my ftplugin/php.vim file.
I've noticed though that these substitutions in TidyUpFormatting show up in the history of all substitutions - for example if I scroll up through the list of substitutions that I've done manually, there they are.

Is there a flag I can use, or indeed some better way, to do this so that these substitutions don't "leak out"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search patterns from `:substitution` inside a function indeed do pollute the search history (*once* for an entire function, not for every `:s`). You can remedy this by adding this at the end of the function:

```
:call histdel('search', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to prefix the substitution commands with the "silent" command, changing the TidyUpFormatting function to:

```
func! TidyUpFormatting()
    let save_cursor = getpos('.')
    silent! %s/\s\+$//ge
    silent! %s/\($\n\s*\)\+\%$//ge
    silent! %s/var_dump /var_dump/ge 
    silent! %s/){/) {/ge
    silent! %s/( /(/ge
    silent! %s/if(/if (/ge
    silent! %s/while(/while (/ge
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction
```